# How to pass value from template on click

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass an index back to python from the user on click in a Flask template. I am already getting information from the same route I'm trying to pass the index to, but I have not figured out how to POST to it. I have put the index value inside the `<button>`, which is inside the `<form>`.

Here's my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
              $('a#test').bind('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('/download_file',
                    function(data) {
                  //do nothing
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
    </script>
    <div>
        <h1>messages list</h1>
        <div>
            <ol>
                {%for index, message in enumerate(messages)%}
                    <li>{{ index }}{{ message.date }}-{{message.name}}</li>
                    <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{index}}" name="index" />
                        <a href="" id=test><button value="index" class='btn btn-default'>Download</button></a>
                    </form>
                {%endfor%}
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `'/download_file'` route

```
@app.route('/download_file', methods=['POST'])
def save_doc():
    index = request.form.get('index')
    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~') + r'\Desktop', filename)
    messages_list[0].document.save(filepath)
    return 'yo'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing on your form that actually submits the value of index. This is assuming you want to do a standard form submit (instead of ajax):

You may want to add something like `<input type="hidden" value="{{index}}" name="index" />` to your form, along with `index = request.form.get('index')` in your route.

Comment: I have added to as I did in above in my question. It looks like because of the POST, my route is never fired. 
I get this message in the console: "GET /download_file HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Comment: Your javascript is performing a GET, while the form will submit a POST, which do you want?

Comment: I want the GET in order to fire `save_doc()` when the user clicks on the button but I want the POST to get the index inside my `save_doc()` function. In order words, I need to know on which element from the list the user clicked on so I can access to right element from the list with `messages_list[0].document.save(filepath)`. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: You won't need to do the ajax get. When the page is rendered, the value of the index input will be already set, and posted when the form is submitted. Try removing the wrapper `<a>` and see what happens. Also, add `type="submit"` to your `button`

Comment: I get the message "The method is not allowed for the requested URL" with this template : `<form method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{index}}" name="index" />
                        <button type="submit" value="index" >Download</button>
                    </form>`

Comment: Ah, missed that you'll also need `action="{{ url_for('save_doc') }}"` on the form, assuming your page url is different to the POST url.

Comment: Ok, this works... but the purpose of the ajax was to not be redirected to a new page after submitting. Would you know how to keep that behavior as well? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You can with a few (template only) tweaks, have a look around at handling form submit via ajax/jquery, give it a try and raise a new question if you get stuck!